# wordpress docker compose to dockerhub

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerhub

I have this ( https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/#define-the-project)  WordPress docker compose file and have a WordPress site running locally.

how do I push this to dockerhub ?

when I use `sudo docker-compose build`

I get `db uses an image, skipping`, `WordPress uses an image, skipping`. so I assume I already have 2 images, I need  to bundle them and push it to dockerhub

I tried `sudo docker-compose push` it does nothing.

any answer would be really helpful, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Dockerhub is for pushing docker images since there is no state in a docker compose file there is nothing to push. 
You can just run the same script on the server that you want to actually execute this on. 
If you want to track changes to your compose file I would recommend Github.